# Is there a way to upload docker images to artifactory though Jenkins plugins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I have a docker image which is created as a part of a build script. Now I need to push the docker image to the local docker registry in artifactory. I'm able to do it from command line. My question is 
1. Is there a way I can push it to the docker registry using the artifactory plugin - using either the file spec / file. -- or -- 
2. I tried the docker plugin but it looks like it expects me to use the dockerfile in the plugin to generate the image and then push it. I want to keep the build part in the script and use the plugin only to push the image.  -- or -- 
3. Is there any other plugin I can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a plugin which abstracts something which is only a few commands? Id add a shell build step (jenkins > Configure project > Add build step > Execute shell) :

```
docker tag "the_image:abcde" "my_artificatory_repo/the_image:1.0.0"
docker push "my_artificatory_repo/the_image:1.0.0"
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing currently. I use artifactory plugin to upload other artifacts that way I'm able to get the artifacts from a particular Jenkins build which is desirable for some users. So was wondering if I can do the same for the docker images.

Comment: You could add the build number that Jenkins has to the tag to identify the build (which is what I do). The Docker API follows a very specific protocol for uploading and downloading images, which is why simply uploading them won't work. @d-g probably has the best answer.

Comment: @retgits You are probably right. That's what I have been doing, tagging the image with the build number but have been looking around for a better way. As users are used to navigating between the build and artifacts for other builds seamlessly it sort of became a requirement. But this should do :)